# VBA Remove the dots and count the digits until space

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a worksheet which contains data like 1.1.2.3 USA, 1.3.4 Canada. I want to loop through the rows and get the digit number. In this case the digits for usa would be 4 and Canada is 3. My idea is to removing the dots and counting until the space. So far I found how to remove the dots

```
strName = Trim("A:A")

lSpace = InStr(1, strName, " ", vbTextCompare)

digits = Trim(Left(strName, lSpace))
```

but I don't know how to combine this with the other parts. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why use VBA for this?

Comment: @jkpieterse I need it for another function

Comment: In VBA you could use `InStr(1, Replace(Replace("1.1.2.3. USA", ".", ""), " ", ""), "USA") - 1` but as jkpieterse says this is absolutely fine to do in a formula as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dots, don't remove them:

```
Sub CountDigits()
    v = Range("A1").Value
    ary = Split(v, " ")
    bry = Split(ary(0), ".")
    MsgBox v & vbCrLf & UBound(bry) + 1
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function

```vb
Function get_digit(your_input As String) As Integer

digit_count = 0
For i1 = 1 To Len(your_input)
    If IsNumeric(Mid(your_input, i1, 1)) Then
        digit_count = digit_count + 1
    ElseIf Mid(your_input, i1, 1) = " " then
        Exit For
    End If
Next i1

get_digit = digit_count
End Function
```